# Firebase Firestore REST Request - Query and Filter

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, request, postman

I have a firestore database on a firebase project. I want to make rest request for filtering or querying data with postman. I'm using "https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects//databases/(default)/documents/" to get the data in a known path in my database. Here is a sample of my database structure:

- users > xxxxx > messages > yyyyy> "sent":"true"

where "users" and "messages" are collections, "xxxxx" and "yyyyy"are autogenerated document ids (xxxxx is autogenerated user id)

What I want to do is to find the "xxxxx"s (users) which have >"sent":"true"< data.

I get success if I know the "xxxxx" and "yyyyy" but I don't know them because they are autogenerated and different from each other in my database and don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to run a Query, as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/runQuery) in the documentation of the REST API.

Since you want to query all the `messages` sub-collections of different `user` documents, you need to "simulate" a [Collection Group Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) in your [`StructuredQuery`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/StructuredQuery). The way to do that is to set the `allDescendants` element to `true` in the [`CollectionSelector`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/StructuredQuery#collectionselector).

So, issuing a POST HTTP Request on the following URL will do the trick:

```
  var URL = "https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<your-project-id>/databases/(default)/documents:runQuery";
```

The body of the POST Request shall contain:

```
    "structuredQuery": {
        "from": [{
            "collectionId": "messages",
            "allDescendants": true
        }],

        "where": {
            "fieldFilter": {
                "field": {
                    "fieldPath": "sent"
                },
                "op": "EQUAL",
                "value": {
                    "stringValue": "true",
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

---

Note that you need to add a single field index to your Firestore DB, as follows:

[image]

---

Note also that, if your field `sent` is of type `Boolean` (and not `String` as shown in your question), you need to use a `booleanValue` element in your [`Value`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/Value) JSON element.

Comment: @ymeksur Hi, did you have the time to look at the proposed answer?

Comment: Hi @RenaudTarnec. I was very busy on these days. Yes I looked your answer and it works great. Thank you very much for your detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add the parent collection/document path to the URL:

`var URL = "https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<your-project-id>/databases/(default)/documents/users/xxxxx:runQuery";`

Then make the `collectionId` "messages" and `allDescendents` false:

```json
"structuredQuery": {
    "from": [{
        "collectionId": "messages",
        "allDescendants": false
    }],

    "where": {
        "fieldFilter": {
            "field": {
                "fieldPath": "sent"
            },
            "op": "EQUAL",
            "value": {
                "stringValue": "true",
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/list#path-parameters)

Comment: then what is that "xxxxx" so pose to mean?

Comment: @Aquiko "xxxxx" is the document ID of the "users" collection, i.e. userId