# How to query for a certain value in a specific field in Firestore through REST?

Tags: r, firebase, rest, google-cloud-firestore

I am using R to GET and POST data using Cloud Firestore REST API. My goal is to get all the data of those documents which have a field `Instructor=="instructor2@fssi.com"`. My collection is names as 'Demographics', documents are named as user emails. There are several fields like below:

[image]

I read collection or document data using this function:

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

read.db <- function(db_endpoint, auth_token) {
  r <- GET(
    sprintf("https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/%s", db_endpoint),
    add_headers(
      "Content-Type" = "application/json",
      "Authorization" = paste("Bearer", auth_token)
    )
  )
  return(r)
}
```

How do I query the database to get all documents where `Instructor=="instructor2@fssi.com"`?

### EDIT

Based on the comment, I tried following:

```
read.db <- function(db_endpoint, auth_token) {
  query <- list(
    structuredQuery = list(
      from = list(
        collectionId = "Demographics",
        allDescendants = TRUE
      ),
      where = list(
        fieldFilter = list(
          field = list(
            fieldPath = "Instructor"
          ),
          op = "EQUAL",
          value = list(
            stringValue = "instructor2@fssi.com"
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
  
  r <- POST(
    sprintf("https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/%s:runQuery", db_endpoint),
    body = toJSON(query),
    add_headers(
      "Content-Type" = "application/json",
      "Authorization" = paste("Bearer", auth_token)
    )
  )
  
  return(r)
}
response <- read.db("projects/MY-PROJECT/databases/(default)/documents", "MY-accessToken")
```

But I get this error:

```
Response [https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/MY-PROJECT/databases/(default)/documents:runQuery]
  Date: 2023-10-17 12:35
  Status: 400
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
  Size: 1.87 kB
[{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"collectionId\" at 'structured_query.from': Proto field is n...
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
...
```

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60486537/firebase-firestore-rest-request-query-and-filter? You'd need the equivalent in R, but that part is mostly unrelated to Firestore then.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thank you for the link. I tried it (see edited post) but get an error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was how the `jsonlite` package was converting the query list to json format. So, I used json directly, and it works:

```
library(httr)
library(glue)

project <- "MYPROJECT"
queryUrl <- paste0("https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/", project, "/databases/(default)/documents:runQuery")
queryBody <- '{
  "structuredQuery": {
    "from": [{ "collectionId": "<<collection>>" }],
    "where": {
      "fieldFilter": {
        "field": {
          "fieldPath": "<<field_path>>"
        },
        "op": "<<operator>>",
        "value": {
          "<<type_value>>": "<<value>>"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'

response <- POST(
  url = queryUrl,
  body = glue(queryBody, collection = "MYCOLLECTION",
              field_path = "Instructor",
              operator = "EQUAL",
              type_value = "stringValue",
              value = "instructor2@fssi.com", .open = "<<", .close = ">>"),
  add_headers("Authorization" = paste("Bearer", "MYACCESSTOKEN"),
              "Content-Type" = "application/json")
)
```