# Cloud Firestore runQuery method does not work as expected in API Explorer

Tags: firebase, rest, google-cloud-firestore

### Goal

From the `Demographics` collection, get all documents that have a field `Instructor` equal to `instructor2@fssi.com`.

### Attempts at API Explorer

##### parent

I am on the [runQuery methods page](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases.documents/runQuery) and trying out the API explorer. The `parent` parameter asks for `projects/{projectId}/databases/{databaseId}/documents` or `projects/{projectId}/databases/{databaseId}/documents/{document_path}`. However, the first one does not work.

If I provide `projects/MYPROJECT/databases/(default)/documents` I see the error message below `parent does not match pattern: /^projects\/[^/]+\/databases\/[^/]+\/documents\/[^/`. I then switch to `projects/MYPROJECT/databases/(default)/documents/Demographics/` that resolves the issue. So, the first argument example seems to be incorrect.

##### Request body

I click the buttons inside the request body text box and build the structured query as follows:

```
{
  "structuredQuery": {
    "where": {
      "fieldFilter": {
        "field": {
          "fieldPath": "Instructor"
        },
        "op": "EQUAL",
        "value": {
          "stringValue": "instructor2@fssi.com"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It looks like this on the page:

[image]

##### Error:

But I get the following error. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"structuredQuery\" at 'document': Cannot find field.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "field": "document",
            "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"structuredQuery\" at 'document': Cannot find field."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

### curl works with some changes in the query:

```
$ curl -X POST "https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/ MYPROJECT /databases/(default)/documents:runQuery" -H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS-TOKEN" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{
  "structuredQuery": {
    "from": [{ "collectionId": "Demographics" }], "where": {

      "fieldFilter": {
        "field": {
          "fieldPath": "Instructor"
        },
        "op": "EQUAL",
        "value": {
          "stringValue": "instructor2@fssi.com"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: Can you share the **exact** and **full** URLs of the queries you execute. To help you we need to see them (with the project name hidden, that's not a problem)

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Sorry, could you clarify what you mean by the URLs of the queries? I see request parameters, request body, and credentials on this page: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases.documents/runQuery

Comment: Exactly what you've just added: `https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/ MYPROJECT/databases/(default)/documents:runQuery` :-)

Comment: This URL is not explicitly needed on the API Explorer though :)

Comment: IMHO it is necessary. Your CURL call is indeed correct and therefore it is normal that it works :-)

Comment: @RenaudTarnec would the docs and API explorer be updated now?

Comment: I don’t think the docs nor the API need to be updated. IMHO they are correct.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Could you please provide an answer to my question about the entries for parameters? Curl only worked when the query was different from what the docs suggested. I get error code 400 when I follow docs.

Comment: How do you call the API? E.g. from a web app, with Axios or fetch?

Comment: API explorer (Try this method sidebar): https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases.documents/runQuery
I also used R and I get a successful response only if the query structure is like the curl command, unlike what the docs suggest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77317459/2829961